# Enable incremental search and highlight while typing a search term?

Tags: regular-expression, command-line, highlight

While I enter a regular expression on the vim command line, I would like to see what matches the partial expression I already wrote.

For example, while writing the command

```
:%s/regular
```

all words `regular` should be highlighted, and the text should be scrolled so that the first of them is visible.

I think it is good enough if it does the highlight only for single line matches, because a match could easily multiple pages intermittently, even if I want to match only one line.

Multiple pages means potentially gigabytes. Of course a single line can be multiple gigabytes itself. The point is: it may be slow.

Is there a way to do this, or anything similar?

Answer (score 12):

This is done by setting just two options: `set is hls` ([incremental search](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27incsearch%27) and [highlight all matches](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27hlsearch%27)).

Make sure you've also read the appropriate help topics, excerpted below: [`:h 'is'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27incsearch%27)

> While typing a search command, show where the pattern, as it was typed
>   so far, matches.  The matched string is highlighted.  If the pattern
>   is invalid or not found, nothing is shown.  The screen will be updated
>   often, this is only useful on fast terminals.
>
> Note that the match will be shown, but the cursor will return to its
>   original position when no match is found and when pressing
>   <kbd>Esc</kbd>.  You still need to finish the search command with
>   <kbd>Enter</kbd> to move the cursor to the match …

and [`:h 'hls'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27hlsearch%27).

> When there is a previous search pattern, highlight all its matches.
>   The type of highlighting used can be set with the [`l`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#highlight-groups)
>   occasion in the [`highlight`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27highlight%27) option.  This uses the
>   "Search" highlight group by default.  Note that only the matching text
>   is highlighted, any offsets are not applied …
>
> When you get bored looking at the highlighted matches, you can turn it
>   off with `:nohlsearch`.  As soon as you use a search command, the
>   highlighting comes back …

Since [Patch 8.1.0271](http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/8.1/8.1.0271), `incsearch` applies to [`:substitute`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute), [`:global`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Aglobal), and [`:vglobal`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Av) (also known as `:s`, `:g`, and `:v`).

In Neovim [`incsearch`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27incsearch%27) still does not affect any command, but there exists another option called `:h 'inccommand'`. Currently it highlights all matches only for [`:h :substitute`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute). Besides this, it can also show a preview window with matched lines: `:set inccommand=split`.

Comment: No, I do not mean in search as with `/` or `?`, I mean for `:`, as in the example.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Please read `:h 'is'` carefully.

Comment: I may miss something, but I do not find what you mean in `:h 'is'`. I already used `incsearch` and `hlsearch`, and they work fine. I have a highlight of the matched strings of a `:%s///` after the execution and a following undo, which is pretty useful. What I mean is having that highlight incrementally. Do you think I should already have that? (I may have broken it somehow.)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel From `:h 'is'`: "Also applies to the pattern in command: ... :substitute ..."

Comment: `I have a highlight of the matched strings of a :%s/// after the execution and a following undo, which is pretty useful` This is what single `set hls` does. We're talking of `set is` now.

Comment: I did not find that text in my `:h 'is'`. I think that means that it is a feature that in my version of vim does not exist. I have VIM 7.4 with patches 1-1907, can you tell me your version?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel It was added in 8.1.0271

Comment: Thank you! If you add that to the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I suggest instead of linking to vimdoc.sf.net (which isn't maintained anymore) to rather link to vimhelp.org. This way, you actually get the correct and updated documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to version 8.1.0271, in order to preview searches in this way you have to adjust your workflow slightly.

First, set up your regular expression by using a normal search, during which highlighting will be active:

```
/regular<CR>
```

Then, you can re-use the regular expression from your search command by leaving the field blank in your substitute command:

```
:%s//replacement
```

An alternative method — if you want to include the actual expression in your command and don't mind a couple of extra keystrokes — is to actually insert the pattern into your `:substitute` command by hitting <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>. This inserts the contents of the search register into the command line. See [`:help c_CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R) for more details.