# How to follow while searching regex in vim?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, bash

In my previous vim, when i typed `/something` and after reaching upto `so` vim started immediately following and with each letter typed i got into new word until i got the perfect. However this following has been disabled for some reasons? How would i enable this?

Comment: This is pretty hard to understand but maybe you're talking about incremental search (`:set incsearch`)....?

Comment: You answered me thanks, please answer in big answer so i can tick mark

Comment: Glad that helped. The answer is already pretty well covered here: [How to highlight matching string while typing a regular expression?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/22063) (though  the title refers to highlighting, incremental search is also in the question). So we'll just mark this as duplicate.

Comment: I updated the title of that one to indicate incremental search as well as highlighting. [Incremental search and highlight while typing a search term?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/22063)

Comment: Good thanks , hmm